# Displaying jQuery UI dialog with multiple checkboxes

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, checkbox, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm trying to display multiple checkboxes and then submit the selected checkboxes as **HTTP GET** (i.e. as parameters in URL string) to the same script:

[image: screenshot]

Here is my simplified test code - **test.php**:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css" title="currentStyle">
        @import "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css";
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
        $('#name').dialog({ autoOpen: false, modal: true });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<p><input type="button" value="Select name"
       onclick="$('#name').dialog('open');"></p>
<div id="name" title="name">

<?php

$NAMES = array(
        'project one',
        'project two',
        'project three',
);

foreach ($NAMES as $name) {
        printf('<p><label><input type="checkbox" name="name" value="%s">%s</label></p>',
                urlencode($name),
                htmlspecialchars(substr($name, 0, 120))
        );
}

?>

</div>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

But for some reason, when I select the first 2 checkboxes click the "Submit" button (sorry for the non-English name in the screenshot), then the script **http://myserver/test.php?** is being submitted and not **http://myserver/test.php?name=project+one&name=project+two** as I would expect.

If I get rid of all JQuery UI stuff, then it works.

What am I doing wrong? (besides using **name="name"** which is because that's a database table column name and doesn't seem to be the reason for this problem anyway)

**UPDATE:**

In my real program (not the above test case) I actually have **several** such dialogs and would like to set some settings in each dialog and **only after that** that click a Submit button. So the Submit button **must be outside** the dialog(s).

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming all the form inputs are checkboxes  you can use the following to compile and submit the details as a GET.

using your original code add the following function

```
function compileInputs(){
var string = '';
var inputs = new Array();

//loop through all checkboxes
$(':checkbox').each(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        inputs.push($(this).attr('name')+"="+$(this).val());
    }
});

string = "?"+inputs.join("&");
window.location.replace(string);
```

}

you will need to change the names of the inputs from name='name' to name='name[]'

then change the submit to a button as follows:

```
<input type="button" onClick='compileInputs()' value='submit'>
```

you will no longer need the `<form>` tags

for a more selective approach:

```
//get all checkboxes from div#name
$('div#name :checkbox').each(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        inputs.push($(this).attr('name')+"="+$(this).val());
    }
});

//get all checkboxes from div#appsversion
$('div#appsversion :checkbox').each(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        inputs.push($(this).attr('name')+"="+$(this).val());
    }
});
//get all checkboxes from div#osversion
$('div#osversion :checkbox').each(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        inputs.push($(this).attr('name')+"="+$(this).val());
    }
});
```

Comment: This works well, thank you. My only problem is, that I have several dialogs: #name, #appsversion, #osversion. I wonder, how to collect the checkboxes inside those div-tags in and elegant way...

Comment: Well the above code will compile the data of all of the checkboxes on the page. If you want to have separate loops for each you could change the selector which loops the inputs. I have added to the solution above.

Comment: Actually you're right - it just works well with 2 dialogs, I've just tried

Comment: Good, I have added some code to show you a more selective approach if you require.

Comment: Do I better need an escape function in there too?

Comment: you may, the best way to find out is to test with some irregular values.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to wrap the whole form in a div and then dialog the new div in the dialog rather than just the div #name

Comment: If I put "submit" button into the div, then it won't be visible

Comment: You should use the jquery ui dialog's buttons property then submit the form with a call to $('form').submit() in the button's callback. Having the submit button outside of the dialog is bad UI

Comment: I actually want to have several such dialogs in my real program -  perform some settings there AND AFTER that click a Submit button. So I have to have my Submit button OUTSIDE the dialog(s).

Comment: I've tried adding a pair of div-tags around the form-tags - this does not help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#submitButton").click(function(){
    $("#formId").submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the dialog is actually the problem, you may have to have your dialogs populate some hidden fields on the page to actually submit.

Here is a very simple sample to get you started.

http://jsfiddle.net/jUH9g/

When you click ok in the dialog it populates the 'names' textbox inside the form that actually gets submitted. In your real code you would change `input type="textbox"` to `input type="hidden"`

```
$("#dlg").dialog({autoOpen: false,
              buttons: {
                  "OK": function () {
                      var names = "";
                      $("input:checkbox").each(function () {
                          if (this.checked) {
                              names += $(this).val() + ",";
                          }
                      });
                      $("#names").val(names);
                  }
              }
         });
```

Comment: Updated answer with some details.

Answer (score 0):

Should you not do name="name[]" . Then on the form submit (however you submit it (AJAX or non AJAX), you can get the "name" array as your post variable and handle it as you may wish. Correct me if I am wrong